# RLC band stop vs. RC low pass filter for switching noise in DC-DC converter

Tags: filter, dc-dc-converter, noise, switching-regulator, passive-filter

I'm working with a DC-DC switching IC that has a fixed switching frequency of 10kHz. I'd like to filter out that switching noise. The load is just an instrumentation amplifier, so the peak current will be under 1mA at ±30V.

Given that I know where the majority noise is likely to be on the frequency spectrum, and that I'll be including the usual decoupling capacitors anyway, are there any benefits in adding an RLC or RC filter to the power path? If so, is there a benefit to using one type over the other, assuming that the series resistance I select is roughly the same (say 3Ω) in both cases? For example, I can see that for similar attenuation at the same *f<sub>c</sub>* the capacitor is smaller for the RLC filter, so that'd be a potential cost saving if it weren't for the added inductor.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand correctly: do you mean to make a comparison between a *lowpass* and a *bandstop* on the power rail? The bandstop will preserve (some) noise, the lowpass won't.

Comment: Yes. The assumption (which may be false, partially hence the question) is that there might be benefits to just notching out the single noisy frequency on the line, instead of applying a low-pass. My intuition says that a low-pass would be better in every practical way, but perhaps there are interesting edge-cases I'm unaware of.

Comment: If you know the noise spectrum then that is the driver to choosing the best filtering system. Please provide that information if you want a practical answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are differences in the time response for the two filters which makes one of them unsuitable for this application. To exemplify, consider the two transfer functions:

$$\begin{align}
H_{LP}(s)&=\dfrac{3}{s^2+3s+3}\tag{1} \\
H_{BS}(s)&=\dfrac{s^2+9}{s^2+s+9}\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

The notch (2) has infinite attenuation at 3 rad/s, whereas the lowpass only ~0.277:

[image: freq]

The first impression would be that the notch is superior to the lowpass when a certain bandwidth is to be attenuated. But this is frequency domain, and the power supply is considered in the time domain due to the dynamic nature of the load: there's always some variation. Which means that the time domain response is to be considered (left step, right impulse):

[image: step+impulse]

Note I have left aside the implicit Dirac that comes out for the impulse response of the notch filter, due to the lowpass + *highpass*. You certainly don't want a differentiator in the path of your supply. Most of the noise may come only from a certain range, the switching frequency, but it's not the only source, and a differentiator will amplify high frequencies. So the frequency domain is only a small part of the whole aspect.

This is why I would recommend the lowpass. Use the bandpass if you have to analyze the signal, not to filter a power supply.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. I had wondered if the phase/inmpulse plot would be relevant here, due to response time, and this confirmed that.

Comment: @Polynomial Thank you. If you think this answered your problem, consider selecting it (the check mark) so that future searches for similar problems will show a question with an accepted answer.

Comment: Whoops, looks like my browser swallowed that click! Accepted.